# Rails: Why a single click doesn't work for an anchor created using Sidr jQuery library?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, sidr

I'm using this library called [Sidr](https://github.com/jesjos/sidr-rails) to create sidebars. I have included all the jQuery and CSS needed, infact it's working, BUT I have to double click instead of 1 Click to actually open the side bar.

This is the code, literally I want to implement this example, but it takes two clicks to work:

```
<a id="left-menu" href="#left-menu">Left Menu</a>
<a id="right-menu" href="#right-menu">Right Menu</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#left-menu').sidr({
name: 'sidr-left',
side: 'left' // By default
});
$('#right-menu').sidr({
name: 'sidr-right',
side: 'right'
});
});
</script>
```

When I take out the turboLinks, it works, but I really need the TurboLinks as well.

Any suggestion or work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sidr library had a conflict with Turbolinks on Rails `3.2` .

Comment: so you couldn't find a fix eh?

Comment: This was while ago, I replaced turbolinks by Wiselinks for a while. Then hired a JS dev to write clean JS with less conflict on Tlinks.